# Is there any manual page for colored shell output?

Tags: terminal, colors, documentation

You know, that colorized output made by special char sequences, for example:

```
echo -e "\e[34m Hello\n \e[0m"
```

This will produce word "Hello" colored in blue. To do this I had to search on the web, and it is hard, because different sources may say something different.
I thought, that there must be some manuals, but I couldn't find them. Even with `apropos color` or something similar.
So, the question is - where I can find reliable manuals?

Comment: You're looking for documentation on ANSI escape codes. (I tend to use the Wikipedia page when I need to look one up.)

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily need to know those escape sequences. Several shells (tcsh, zsh, fish at least) have builtin support to output in colours without having to explicitely write those sequences.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are too many sources of information to list in this page:

- The command `echo -e` uses an [extension](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) to render `\e` as ASCII 27 (octal 33 or "\033").  The portable way to print these uses [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) (POSIX).  Compare with standard [`echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) (POSIX).
- Your example can be rewritten as

  `printf "\033[34m Hello\n \033[0m"`
- the standard for the color escapes is [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) (Control Functions for Coded Character Sets).
- In ECMA-48, 8.3.117 SGR - SELECT GRAPHIC RENDITION lists control sequences for setting 8 foreground and 8 background colors.
- It also lists codes 39/49 "default display colour (implementation-defined)" and 38/48 "reserved for future standardization;
  intended 
  for setting character foreground colour as specified in
  ISO 8613-6 [CCITT Recommendation T.416]".  That is, there is a recommendation by another organization but it was not (so far, after 24 years) made part of the standard.
- reading it closely, you may notice that the standard is vague in many places, allowing different interpretations.  It describes the *syntax* of these control sequences but does not describe their *behavior*.  For that, you have to go to the documentation for the respective terminals.
- documentation for xterm is found in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), which assumes a familiarity with DEC documentation found on http://vt100.net
- for other terminals, their manual pages may enumerate the controls (as done for Linux console in [console_codes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)).
- other terminals document themselves as "xterm"; for discussion see the xterm FAQ *[Comparing versions, by counting controls](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#compare_versions)*.  Fortunately, the color controls are *mostly* compatible (but see the ncurses FAQ *[My terminal shows some uncolored spaces](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bce_mismatches)*).
- you can also read the manual pages for [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html), which allows you to use [`terminfo`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) capabilities in a shell script.  Your example could be rewritten as

  ```
  printf '%s\n' "$(tput setaf 4)Hello$(tput setaf 0)"
  ```
- a few sources such as the [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) and the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html) mention color, but (even these) as a rule have gaps and omissions and are not helpful with respect to ECMA-48.
- most of the other sources which you will find with a web-search copy from other sources (such as those cited), etc., and as a rule pay little attention to the actual standard.

Comment: The relevant section in ECMA-48 seems to be 8.3.117 - "SGR - SELECT GRAPHIC RENDITION". It has the only mentions of the word "blue", and the codes found there work at least in my XTerm.

Comment: yes - I'll add a clarification.

Comment: It's really great answer - wish all answers be like yours

Comment: xterm also support 256-color mode, presumably this is documented in one of the manuals above.

Comment: See http://wynnnetherland.com/journal/a-stylesheet-author-s-guide-to-terminal-colors/ for a bunch of useful info including the grc package which can do all sorts of colorizing things with command output.