# How to add colour to /etc/sudoers.lecture

Tags: shell, sudo, colors

Having set a [lecture](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107582/how-can-i-find-and-or-print-sudos-lecture-file) with `Default lecture=always` and `Default lecture_file=/etc/sudoers.lecture`, I would like to add colour to it. ANSI escape characters show without escaping, and creating a wrapper function displays it every time I use sudo, even if the password is in the cache.

Comment: What is a `lecture`?

Comment: @k.stm This is described in the `sudoers(5)` manual.  It is the short text that is outputted upon first using `sudo`, which (by default) reminds the user to use the command responsibly.

Comment: Cannot reproduce here; using the appropriate [`tput`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241450/117549) output, I created a file that sudo dutifully outputted in color. How did you produce the /etc/sudoers.lecture file?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9957/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I also don't know how `tput` works.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I do (now) know how `tput` works, but I cannot get it to display colour when put in sudoers,lecture.

Comment: @gadzooks02: are you displaying the lecture in the same type of terminal as you generate the colors in? The value of `$TERM` is the critical piece, I think.

Comment: @JeffSchaller what do you mean by 'generating' the colours?

Comment: I imagine you'd use `tput` to generate the colored text?

Comment: If by 'generate', you mean adding `$(tput setaf <number>)` to sudoers.lecture, then yes

Comment: @JeffSchaller NVM, I found what you mean: `echo $(tput setaf <number>)<text> >> /etc/sudoers.lecture`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```bsh
echo $(tput setaf <colour>)<text>$(tput sgr0) >> /etc/sudoers.lecture
```

adds coloured text to /etc/sudoers.lecture